# How do you count the occurrence of same data set in two columns-set in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

How can we count the occurrence of each set of data? For eg I want to check how many time the customer country in column A comes alongside country in column B ie (How many times Australia-Australia occurs in column A and column B?). The result for unique occurrences are place in right hand side of the sheet. I have found out unique occurrences of the sets and want to count how many times each occur.

Comment: You can use countif formula. but your example picture does not make it clear on what columns you want to be checking from and against.

Comment: I have updated the description, can you please have a look at the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, `SUMPRODUCT` is your friend:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(($A$2:$A$11&$B$2:$B$11)=(D2&E2)))
```

[image]

Comment: You are a lifesaver

Comment: If the answer helped you, please select it as your answer. Amongst other things, it will help to close the query

Answer (score 3):

You asked for a formula, but a pivot table can do the same thing faster; and without requiring you to create the table for unique countries (option found under insert, usually the first button in the ribbon):

[image]

This is how it looks like after pulling the fields in the right 'boxes', the 'Tabular' report layout is selected and the subtotals turned off.

You can make 'Australia' repeat itself too under report layout if so you wish.

Comment: How do I add the count of Trip in the Values section of the pivot(the bottom right section). I have added customer and trip column in the row labels

Comment: @SamitPaudel You just pull it from the list of fields again, into the values box.

Comment: Thanks man I've learned a very useful tool today because of you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNTIFS` function as below.

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B,E2)`

Adjust the ranges to suit your data and copy down.